# List Always Being Reset?

Tags: python, list

So basically, I have the following text file with the names of some students and their grades and I need to compute their average scores using a dictionary where the keys are their names and the values are a list of their scores. I have the following code. In the while loop, however, I reset the valuesList (containing the scores of one of the kids) and I reset it so i can add the scores of the next kid and the scores don't get mixed up. I tried a variety of solutions but none of them worked. I'm not sure why it re-appends the value of the next kid's scores and why it just remains as an empty list. So any help?

```
inFile = open('grades.txt','r')
outFile = (inFile.read ()).split()
scoresDic = {}
index = 0 #traverse through the list
index2 =0
keysList = [] #store the keys
valuesList = []
for i in range(len(outFile)):
    if outFile [index] not in keysList and outFile [index].isalpha () == True: #if its a name that hasnt been stored in list already
        keysList.append (outFile [index]) #add it to the keys
    index+=1
index = 0
while True:
    if outFile [index2] == keysList [index]:
        valuesList.append (outFile[index2+1]) #if its the name of one of the boys, add his score the values list
    index2+=1

    if index2 == len (outFile):
        scoresDic [keysList [index]] = valuesList #map the boys name to his list of grades into the dictionary
        index+=1
        index2 = 0 
        valuesList [:] =[]  #reset the list and variables for next kids name
    if index == len (keysList):
        break
print (scoresDic)
'''should print (in some order)
Gilliam 78.75
Jones 83.0
Cleese 85.75
Chapman 95.0
Idle 91.0
Palin 85.0
'''
```

.txt File Contents:

```
Cleese 80
Gilliam 78
Jones 69
Jones 90
Cleese 90
Chapman 90
Chapman 100
Palin 80
Gilliam 82
Cleese 85
Gilliam 80
Gilliam 75
Idle 91
Jones 90
Palin 90
Cleese 88
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for name, grade in [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('grades.txt')]:
   d[name].append(float(grade))

final_results = {name:sum(grades)/float(len(grades)) for name, grades in d.items()}

for name, grade in final_results.items():
   print(name, grade)
```

Output:

```
Gilliam 78.75
Jones 83.0
Cleese 85.75
Chapman 95.0
Idle 91.0
Palin 85.0
```

Comment: This is pretty good. In the interest of simplicity, though, I'd read and parse the data in the same loop instead of having that list comprehension there.

Comment: Also, may I suggest using better names than `a` and `b` in the dictionary comprehension :)

Comment: @AKX Thank you for your suggestions! Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Just `for line in open('grades.txt'): name, grade = line.strip('\n').split(); ...` (damnit, no newlines in comments...) would be more easily understandable, I believe :)